# What is wrong with this code for an Elo rating system

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a program that automatically changes the person's elo rating. I ran into a problem that I can't seem to solve. Here's the code:

```
        Liam=1000; 
        Stefan=1000; 
        Dylan=1000; 
        Dennis=1000; 
        Daniel=1000; 
        K=32; 
        //eloX is the player who won 
        var ratingChange = function(PlayerX,PlayerY){ 
        //Expected Winning percentage of player X 
        var EWP_X = 1/(1+10^((PlayerY-PLayerX)/400)); 
        //WP=Winning Percentage 
        WP=1; 
       //Player X rating change 
       PlayerX = PlayerX+K*(WP-EWP_X); 
       console.log(PLayerX)
       }; 
       ratingChange(Liam,Dylan)
```

Whenever I test this Javascript I get the error "PlayerX is not defined". I'm rusty in Javascript so I'm sure it's an obvious problem that I over looked. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I bet it says "P**L**ayerX is not defined""

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript is case sensitive. L should be l:

```
var EWP_X = 1/(1+10^((PlayerY-PlayerX)/400)); 

console.log(PlayerX)
```

Please refer to the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zeskysee/vd06gox9/

Comment: Thanks. Didn't notice those caps even for a second after you posted the answer. I test the code and it still doesn't work. Then I copy and paste the fiddle code beside mine and find the other caps mistake. Thank you for your help.